# Return type of getClass method

Tags: java, generics

The documentation for the method `getClass()` in `Object` says:

> The actual result type is `Class<? extends |X|>` where `|X|` is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is called.

So why does `foo` compile but not `bar`?

```
static void foo(String s) {
    try {
        Class<? extends String> clazz = s.getClass();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

static <T> void bar(T t) {
    try {
        Class<? extends T> clazz = t.getClass();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

**Edit**

I've accepted yshavit's answer, as it clearly answers my question, but I'm still curious to know why they defined it like this. They could have defined it to have type `Class<? extends T>` where `T` is the static type of the expression. It isn't clear to me why it's necessary to erase the type information at this stage. It makes sense if the type is `List<String>`, but not if it's `T`. I'll up-vote any answer that explains this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: getClass() of bounded type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144556/java-getclass-of-bounded-type)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> where `|X|` is the **erasure** of the static type of the expression *(emphasis added)*

The [erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) of `T t` is `Object`, so `|X|` is `Object` in that case. That means that the result type is `Class<? extends Object>` (which is essentially equivalent to `Class<?>`).

The erasure of `String s`, on the other hand, is `String` (since `String` is a [reifiable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html) type -- ie, not generic).