# Why does getClass return a Class<? extends |X|>?

Tags: java

I tried to understand what is the reason for `getClass` method to return `Class<? extends |X|>`?

From the [openjdk](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Object.java/?v=source) near `public final native Class<?> getClass();`:

> The actual result type is `Class<? extends |X|>`
>   where `|X|` is the erasure of the static type of the
>   expression on which `getClass` is called.

Why can't `getClass` have the same type such as `XClass.class`, for example:

```
class Foo {}
Foo fooInstance = new Foo();
Class<Foo> fc = Foo.class; // Works!
Class<Foo> fc2 = fooInstance.getClass(); // Type mismatch ;(
Class<?> fc3 = fooInstance.getClass(); // Works!
Class<? extends Foo> fc4 = fooInstance.getClass(); // Works!
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332856/what-is-meant-by-the-erasure-of-the-static-type-of-the-expression-on-which-it-i and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144556/java-getclass-of-bounded-type

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Foo foo = new SubFoo();
```

What do you expect `foo.getClass()` to return?  (It's going to return `SubFoo.class`.)

That's part of the whole point: that `getClass()` returns the class of the real object, not the reference type.  Otherwise, you could just write the reference type, and `foo.getClass()` would never be any different from `Foo.class`, so you'd just write the second one anyway.

(Note, by the way, that `getClass()` actually has its own special treatment in the type system, not like any other method, because `SubFoo.getClass()` does not return a subtype of `Foo.getClass()`.)