# Java: Casting Object to primitive array using Class.cast()

Tags: java, arrays, object, casting, primitive

Casting a known primitive array masquerading as an Object back to it's original primitive array type using the Class.cast method involves breaking the operation up into two assignments first before it's use can be correctly compiled.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object src = new int[]{1,2,3}; 
        castAndSet(src);
    }

    // assign index i of src to dest after casting src to int[]
    public static void castAndSet(Object src){ 
        int[] dst = new int[]{4,5,6};
        int i = 0; // assume array length greater than zero.
        if(dst.getClass().equals(src.getClass())){ // assert both are same class
            // src should also be an int[], so no ClassCastException to worry about

            dst[i] = ((int[])src)[i];  //this works of course
            // but can we cast and set using Class#cast method?

            // shouldn't we be able to do this?
            dst[i] = dst.getClass().cast(src)[i]; // doesn't compile
            dst[i] = (dst.getClass()).cast(src)[i]; // doesn't compile
            dst[i] = ((dst.getClass()).cast(src))[i]; // doesn't compile

            // let's break it apart
            var dstClass = dst.getClass(); // dstClass is Class<? extends int[]>
                                           // as per getClass javadocs.
            dst[i] = dstClass.cast(src)[i]; // still doesn't compile
                                            // array type expected;found capture<? extends int[]>

            // instead we have to break it apart twice
            var dstClass2 = dst.getClass(); // dstClass is Class<? extends int[]>
            var src2 = dstClass2.cast(src); // src2 is int[], magic
            dst[i] = src2[i]; // compiles.

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dst));
        }
        else throw new RuntimeException("objects are not of the same array class");
    }
}
```

Parenthesized operations seems like this cast and set should be a one liner but there is some implicit conversion going on during assignment to a variable. The 'var' keyword is used and no where is an explicit type hinted at to guide this implicit conversion from what I can tell.

What is going on?

Comment: Why are you using `Class.cast` in the first place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The return type of `dst.getClass` is `Class<? extends int[]>`, instead of `Class<int[]>` which you might have expected. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37796705/5133585) if you don't understand why.

The return type of `Class<T>.cast` is `T`, but what if `T` is `? extends int[]` like in your code? [Capture conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10) applies, and `Class<? extends int[]>` becomes a `Class<CAPTURE>`, where `CAPTURE` is a fresh type variable, with `int[]` as its upper bound. The idea is that the compiler doesn't know anything about `? extends int[]`, except that it is a subtype of `int[]`. Of course, we as humans know that `int[]` does not have any subtypes except itself.

In any case, the return type of `cast` is `CAPTURE`. `CAPTURE` is a type variable, not an array type, so you cannot use array indexing `[i]` on it.

You are able to do:

```
var src2 = dst.getClass().cast(src);
dst[i] = src2[i];
```

because although `dst.getClass().cast(src)` is of type `CAPTURE`, [type projection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.5) applies when you assign that to a `var`. From the [language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4.1):

> If the LocalVariableType is `var`, then let `T` be the type of the initializer expression when treated as if it did not appear in an assignment context, and were thus a standalone expression. The type of the local variable is the upward projection of `T` with respect to all synthetic type variables mentioned by `T` ([§4.10.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.5)).

> The upward projection of a type T with respect to a set of restricted type variables is defined as follows:
>
> ...
>
> - If `T` is a restricted type variable, then the result is the upward projection of the upper bound of `T`.

So `CAPTURE` here gets projected to its upper bound `int[]`.

Of course, `int[] src2 = dst.getClass().cast(src);` also compiles because `CAPTURE` has an upper bound of `int[]`, so `int[]` is a supertype of `CAPTURE`.

Comment: Interesting to note that Eclipse reports compile error for `src2[i]` whereas JDK21 javac is happy.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you.  I guess my follow up is if there is any way to force this upward projection without explicitly involving the literal <primitive type>[] OR assignment in order to keep it one statement? The following is as succinct as I can make it.

      `var s = dst.getClass().cast(src); dst[k]=s[j];`

Comment: @JNellis No, I can't find anywhere else where type projection can occur except local variable declarations. At the end of the day, you can just not cast at all and use `Array.get`/`Array.set` instead. `Array.set(dst, k, Array.get(src, j))`

Comment: @Sweeper  thanks again, I appreciate your time spent on this.

Comment: I wanted to add that performance-wise, the literal cast version `dst[k] = ((int[])src)[j];` vs the Class.cast version `var s = dst.getClass().cast(src); dst[k]=s[j];` ended up being the exact same if anyone was curious.  Whereas Array.get/set I've known to be very poor performance due to all the checks it does every call. From 25-100x slower in this scenario.